# Add persistent global function across pages via window, or localstorage, etc

Tags: javascript, local-storage, global-variables, global, event-listener

I am trying to hide an icon on a page I can't edit directly.  I need to add a function that has in it `document.getElementById('icon').style.display = 'none';`. I don't need help with the function.

So more in-depth: there is a **page, let's call it unEditPage, that I cannot edit directly**.  It doesn't share any resources like our other pages on the website do - aka no global js files or css, but it would share localstorage - etc...

unEditPage and all other pages that I have access to are all on the same domain.

I've tried attaching an event listen to the window and fire on url contains, but that listener is destroyed on page navigation.

Solution would be something I can inject in another page that carries over to the unEditable page.  Something maybe using unload, localstorage, cookies, or global something.

Comment: If you can't edit the code, then I'm afraid that there is little you can do.

Comment: What is your goal here? What is your use case? Is this a pen-testing exercise?

Comment: @Bergi it is simply to hide an icon on a page that we control, but can't access directly.  Furthermore, I no longer need to do this, but I'd like to continue the convo more on the pen-test side.  Can someone inject a global function that is persistent across page nav or localstorage..?

Comment: It's not possible to inject/persist the script into the uneditpage when someone loads just that page (unless you have a XSS vulnerability in there). However, if someone loads another page first where you can inject the functionality, you can intercept navigation from there, load the uneditpage via ajax, and manipulate the address bar using [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) so that all your code stays running but the user sees the uneditpage now. This is standard practice in single page applications.